# deserialization without knowing type

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization

I've got a class structure a where I have two classes that derive from a common base.

I receive an xml stream, that I want to deserialize into one of the two derived types, but I don't know if root element is Derived1 or Derived2.  The stream may not be seekable, so I can't read to find the root element name, then re-position at the beginning of the stream.

Is it possible to use the XmlSerializer or possibly other serializer to deserialize and return the correct type?  I am currently getting an InvalidOperationException stating "There is an error in XML document (1,2) with an inner exception  was not expected."

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("Derived1", Namespace = "http://mynamespace", IsNullable = false)]
public class Derived1: MyBase
{
    ...
}

/// <remarks/>

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("Derived2", Namespace = "http://mynamespace", IsNullable = false)]
public class Derived2: MyBase
{
    ...
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Derived1))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Derived2))]
public class MyBase
{
    ...
}


public MyBase Deserialize(Stream message)
{
    Type[] types = new Type[]
    {
        typeof(Derived1),
        typeof(Derived2)
    };

    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(MyBase), types);
    
    MyBase result = (MyBase)ser.Deserialize(message);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you embed the whole structure in a non changing root? That would be class only used for this purpose. It would include a single property `public MyBase Root { get; set; }`.

Comment: Not elegant but you could test if you [CanDeserialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.candeserialize?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Can you use try and catch? If you serialise using one type and it throws, try the other one.

Comment: Crowcoder -  that could work.